# Unable to find module with Gradle path ':volley'. Linking to library 'volley-unspecified' instead

Tags: android

I have tried a tutorial, it works for me in one app but when I am trying to apply it to a different app, it is giving warning

> Warning:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':volley'. Linking to library 'volley-unspecified' instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065477/best-way-to-incorporate-volley-or-other-library-into-android-studio-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click project, Select "Configure Project Subset ..." and select your module, rebuild your project.