# No manifest attribute Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I imported the volley library as .jar file and I added it as a library
(right click >add as library ).

When I try to run the app I get the Error

```
no main manifest attribute, in /Users/ervincosic/AndroidStudioProjects/AirportCab247/app/libs/library-1.0.19.jar
```

[image: See here the screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be connected with Volley. Clean project if that doesn't work try to remove it and compile again.

Comment: do you maybe know how to connect it properly ?

Comment: way I did it: download Volley and place in 'app/libs/volley'. and in gradle add: compile project(':volley')

Comment: @ErvinCosic You should probably add it as a dependency via the dependencies menu. `Project Structure` -> `Module` -> `Dependencies` -> click `+` -> choose `Library Dependency` -> type volley -> hit Return -> select com.android.volley -> click Ok

Comment: Instead of downloading Volley, you can use gradle copy. Add this line to your repositiry: compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be connected with Volley. Clean project if that doesn't work try to remove it and compile again. To do that you can simply add dependency to your `build.gradle` file. You should have something like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion ...
    ....


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        ...

        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'
    }
```

If you want to read about other methods of importing **[VOLLELY, click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065477/best-way-to-incorporate-volley-or-other-library-into-android-studio-project)**.

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

Comment: You should have 2 build.gradle files in your project

Comment: in the other file include ':app', ':volley' still does not work

Comment: @ErvinCosic  Edited my answer