# Volley not appearing on Android Studios

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, xml-parsing

I am trying to follow a tutorial on parsing XML data, however he uses a requestQueue and initiates it using Volley. 
For some reason when I try to use `Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`, android studio doesn't seem to register Volley as a thing and registers as an error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Comment: Have you added volley library to your project?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that? Sorry, am new to android development.

Comment: Which environment r u using? android studio?

Comment: You need to add volley as library in your project. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065477/best-way-to-incorporate-volley-or-other-library-into-android-studio-project

Comment: Yes, think I got it. Added compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' to my dependencies. Thanks for the help!