# How to download Volley.jar from jcenter?

Tags: android-volley, jcenter

I'm trying to download Volley and i cant find any link related to download volley from jcenter 
Can anyone Give me the latest volley jar to download
thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to incorporate Volley (or other library) into Android Studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065477/best-way-to-incorporate-volley-or-other-library-into-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are multiple ways to install Volley without getting a direct download, I absolutely understand the need to get the downloadable aar file.

As of *2017-03-24*, [**this link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljmltb9c6tvu03l/volley-1.0.0.aar?dl=1) is the current version of volley (1.0.0). I cloned the main repo and ran a build to generate the aar file this morning.