# Generate a single .jar with only androidTest code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-uiautomator

How can I generate a single .jar file with only my Android Test classes at src/androidTest?

The code I have is working when I run only the test class or the package, but I would like to be able to generate and push the .jar file containing all the tests and execute it via adb shell. (my project doesn't have any app source code)

I'm currently using Android Studio with Gradle.

Thanks

Comment: Execute .jar via adb shell? Maybe you meant .apk with tests?

Comment: From the specs I've found, you can run your jar file inside the cellphone with **adb shell uiautomator runtest File.jar**

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218295/android-gradle-build-system-create-jar-not-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special gradle task to run tests on connected device or emulator

```
gradle :module_name:connectedCheck
```

Test results will be available in `./build/outputs/androidTest-results` folder.

But if you want to do it in two separate steps (assemble apk & run it via adb shell), use this command to assemble the apk with tests

```
gradle :module_name:assembleAndroidTest
```

Find out the .apk file in `./build/outputs/apk` folder of your module.
Let install it with command

```
gradle :module_name:installDebugAndroidTest
```

or

```
adb install ./module_name/build/outputs/apk/module_name-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
```

Now start the tests

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e package <package_with_tests> <package_from_manifest>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

The results appear in STDOUT.

Comment: Of course, you can use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034466/how-to-create-an-android-library-jar-with-gradle-without-publicly-revealing-sour to generate a .jar file with tests, but I am not sure it is a right way.

Comment: The apk was generated with the assembleAndroidTest command you gave, but how can I run the tests on the device and have the results?

Comment: To install apk use command `adb install ./module_name/build/outputs/apk/module_name-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk   
`

Comment: After than run test with command `adb shell am instrument -w -e package <package_to_run_tests> <package_from_manifest>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`  
Your test results appear in STDOUT

Comment: I updated my answer to have it complete for all cases

Comment: Thank you, it worked! The only difference I had in my case is that I choose to use AndroidJUnitRunner instead of InstrumentationTestRunner, but the approach is the same. 
This page also helped: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html